# Incompatible Double Casting - Not Detected by Compiler

Tags: c#, casting

In testing some code this evening, I naively tried a double-cast to convert a `List` to `IQueryable` (Note: I know about `.AsQueryable()`, please read the whole question):

```
var data = (IQueryable<MyType>)(List<MyType>)Application["MyData"];
```

I didn't think about whether or not that was valid, but I noticed that there were no errors in Visual Studio, and I was able to compile the code without errors, so I assumed it would work.  But after I published the web application, and went to view the page, I got the following error (as expected):

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyType]' to
>   type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[MyType]'.

Even though the type of `Application["MyData"]` isn't known at compile-time, isn't it known that I'm trying to cast from `List<MyType>` to `IQueryable<MyType>`, which is not valid?  Why don't I get a compiler error in this case?

Comment: Remember, the meaning of cast is "hey compiler, I know that this conversion is valid even if you don't, so believe me". The compiler will believe you unless it can *prove* that you can't possibly be right, and even in some of those cases it will still allow it. Don't put a typecast in a program unless you *know* that it will work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) class is not sealed, so the the compiler cannot be *sure* that the cast from `List<T>` to `IQueryable<T>` is invalid.

Suppose you define a subclass like this

```
class QueryableList<T> : List<T>, IQueryable<T>
{
    ...
}
```

Then the cast *would* be valid.

Comment: +1 D'oh, I should have thought of that!  My brain must be getting tired :)  I whipped up a little test where I tried double-casting between a custom interface and a custom sealed class, and the compiler *does* complain.  As always, I'm impressed at the sophistication of the .NET tooling.

Answer (score 1):

It just because `IQueryable<T>` is an interface.

```
var anywayListOfMyType=
    (IWhatsoever)(IFormatProvider)(IIntellisenseBuilder)new List<MyType>();
```

would compiles.

p.s.

`IWhatsoever` doesn't really exist.